# $watch element.scrollHeight not triggered

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a `div` inside a `td` tag (which is inside a `tr` tag). This `div` has a custom directive that needs to `$watch` the `scrollHeight` of the element:

```
<tr ng-show="showRow">
    <td>
      <div my-custom-directive>My very long text</div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

and for the directive:

```
appDrct.directive('myCustomDirective', [function() {

   return {
       restrict : 'A',
       compile : function(elem, attr, linker) {


          return function(scope, element, attributes) {
             scope.$watch(element[0].scrollHeight, function(){
                console.log('triggered');
             })
          }
       }
    }
}])
```

The `showRow` variable changes through a `ng-click`.

The problem is that the `$watch` is never triggered (except the very first time) even though the `scrollHeight` changes due to the `ng-show` (`scrollHeight` is equal to 0 when `ng-show` is equal to `false`).

I first thought it was because I had to use `$scope.$apply` but I don't know where to put it...

Comment: It doesn't matter... angularJS allows both!

Comment: Anyway it doesn't solve my problem...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot watch a direct object reference (which is what you're trying to do). You either watch a property of the current scope (by providing the name of the property as a string), or you watch a function, which returns the new value.

Change your watch to:

```
scope.$watch(function(){ return element[0].scrollHeight }, function(){
    console.log('triggered');
});
```

On another note, as commenters point out, you should reference your directive using dashes, rather than camel-case, in the DOM.

Answer (score -1):

Change myCustomeDirective to my-custome-directive in html

```
<tr ng-show="showRow">
    <td>
      <div my-custome-directive>My very long text</div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

in directive

```
appDrct.directive('myCustomDirective', [function() {

   return {
       restrict : 'A',
       compile : function(elem, attr, linker) {


          return function(scope, element, attributes) {
             scope.$watch(function(){ return element[0].scrollHeight },
                 function(){
                       console.log('triggered');
                 })
          }
       }
    }
}])
```

Comment: It doesn't answer the question, please remove it!

Comment: I was about to answer. Here net is slow.

Comment: You just copied the answer from @Thor

Comment: How could you say that. This is the answer. How can answer it differently. I was supposed to answer it. But I was little slow to post it.

Comment: If you were supposed to answer it, were a little slow to post it, and there's already an accepted answer with exact same content, then this answer serves no purpose at all. It's just duplicate unless it brings something new to the table.

Comment: Actually there is 2 mistakes in his question. The accepted answer cottected only one answer. So if some one else try that answer it wont work. So there is something diffrent in my answer and also this must be the accepted answer. I dont understand why he down vote it. My answer is the exact answer for his question. I dont have any problem. But pls dont make me feel bad.